# APK rejected from Google Play because Cordova is too old, but Cordova is up to date

Tags: android, cordova, apk, android-security, google-developers-console

Here are the versions installed:

```
matt@dev ~/Projects/proj-mobile (release)
cordova platforms ls
Installed platforms:
  android 5.2.2
  ios 4.2.1
Available platforms:
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  osx ~4.0.1
  webos ~3.7.0

matt@dev ~/Projects/proj-mobile (release)
cordova -v
6.3.1
```

But here is the message I'm getting:

[image]

And the details:

[image]

Comment: you probably have an old cordova.js somewhere in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can only be two issues:

- You are using an old version of cordova. check your file there might be someware an old version of some file left.
- Your config.xml specifies a version number. Google play does not let
  you upload the same version so each time you upload to google play
  this number has to be incremented.

Comment: You're right, the “phonegap-facebook-plugin” was importing its own cordova install in bower_components, and the version was 3.3.0.